# How to add new process after account creation in PrestaShop?

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I need to link my installed PrestaShop to another web application using its API. This new process must be done after account creation or after its confirmation (By sent email). As I did not do anything on developing PrestaShop, I am not familiar with its folders, files, controllers and their methods. I found something in `controller/front/AuthController.php` but I am not sure is it correct or not?
May you help me please to find the exact position to insert my new codes?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to execute something when an account is created in Front office, you can use the hook actionCustomerAccountAdd. On account creation, it will execute:

```
Hook::exec('actionCustomerAccountAdd', array(
                            '_POST' => $_POST,
                            'newCustomer' => $customer
                        ));
```

So you could create a module that uses this information, like blocknewsletter module:

```
public function hookActionCustomerAccountAdd($params)
{
    // do something
}
```

If you want to execute even when the customer is added in backoffice, you need to override the class Customer. Create a file in override/classes/Customer.php with:

```
class Customer extends CustomerCore 
{
     public function add($autodate = true, $null_values = true)
     {
           $res = parent::add($autodate, $null_values);
           if($res){
                  // customer is added -> do something
           }
     }
}
```